# UITextView's format disappeared after setting it's .text property in Today Extension in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, today-extension

So first, I set a UITextView and set text's colour to white and align to centre in Storyboard, and everything is working well:

[image: storyboard]

[image: working fine]

Then I go into the `TodayViewController.swift` and add the following code:

```
class TodayViewController: UIViewController, NCWidgetProviding {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textView.text = "Some new text"
    }
}
```

But when I run my Today Extension, we can see that all format is lost:

[image: format lost?]

So how can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: I just make an outlet and check...and its just fine....display in center

Comment: @Bhavin it's working when `Selectable` is true, but if it is false, it just don't work

Comment: Yes true....not working when selectable not checked

Comment: @Bhavin so any solution?

Comment: I tried...but not found

Comment: Have you tried using a `NSAtributtedString`, and setting the font color, size, etc. directly to the string instead of the `UITextView`?

Comment: Don´t know if you have found a solution yet, but check my answer it solves the issue.